# Crear un método con un array con números consecutivos y longitud elegida por usuario JAVA

Tags: java, array

Tengo que crear un método que que devuelva un array con números naturales consecutivos y la longitud elegida por el usuario, el caso es que estoy bloqueado con la longitud, os paso mi código para ver donde puedo mejorar:

```
public static int []tablaConsecutivos(int numeroInicial, int longitud){
    
    int []num = new int[longitud];
    
    for(int i=numeroInicial; i <= numeroInicial+longitud-1 ;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    return num;
}
```

Creo que el fallo estará en el *for* pues no tengo claro hasta donde tiene que llegar puesto que en los números negativos falla.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Para empezar, no estás guardando ningún número en el array. Por lo demás, el código debería funcionar con números negativos o positivos.

Comment: He añadido en el for lo siguiente:

 for(int i=numeroInicial; i <= numeroInicial+longitud ;i++){
            num[i]=numeroInicial;
            System.out.println(num[i]);
            
        }

Con la idea de que el vector se rellene con i pero sigue dando error. Es cierto que el código funciona bien y con números negativos, la lógica está bien, pero al rellenar el vector encuentro el error y ando muy bloqueado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya entiendo lo que te pasa. Imagino que tu código habrá que dado así:

```
int []num = new int[longitud];

for(int i=numeroInicial; i <= numeroInicial+longitud-1 ;i++){
    num[i] = numeroInicial;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Este código no tiene ningún sentido y obviamente no hace lo que esperas por la sencilla razón de que si `numeroInicial` que es por donde empieza el `for` es negativo, estarías asignando un valor negativo a `i` y entonces `num[i]` produciría una excepción al intentar acceder a un índice menor que `0` de un array. Así que necesitas otra variable para ir utilizándola como índice para acceder al array. Además, lo que hay que guardar el en array es `i` que irá incrementándose desde `numeroInicial` hasta `numeroInicial + longitud - 1` (incluido el último ya que el signo del `for` es `<=` menor o igual):

```
int []num = new int[longitud];
int index = 0;    
for(int i=numeroInicial; i <= numeroInicial+longitud-1 ;i++){
    num[index++] = i;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Pfff vaya error más tonto era... He rebuscado por toda la web y no encontraba algo así. Esto me servirá para no cometer el mismo error nuevamente.

MUCHAS GRACIAS! :)